# How to move HTML nodes while preserving AngularJS data binding?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angularjs

The angular-ui/ui-map module is capable of moving a HTML node from any position in the DOM into a Google Maps InfoWindow while preserving the data binding.

```
<div ui-map-info-window="myInfoWindow">
  <h1>Marker {{marker.id}}}</h1>
  Lat: <input ng-model="currentMarkerLat">, ...
</div>
```

This does only work, because the Google Maps v3 API allows it to pass a HTML Node as content parameter.

```
//ui-map.js line 55 - 60
opts.content = elm[0]; //elm[0] is the HTML Node
...
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(opts);
```

We tried to replicate this functionality with OpenLayers.Popup, but failed to move the HTML Node without loosing its ng-databinding:

```
//contentDiv is the OpenLayers.Popup container for holding the HTML content to be displayed in the popup
this.contentDiv.appendChild(elm[0]);
```

This does not work and only displays the HTML Element without any AngularJS binding (e.g. the mustaches are being displayed, not the variable values).

**What is the trick Google Maps API v3 uses to preserve the bindings?**

Comment: would need to use `$compile()` or move data instead so angular does automatic digest. Suggest you create simplified demo of what you have so far